# Alinhar botão embaixo CSS

Tags: css3, bootstrap-3

Estou utilizando o bootstrap, porém, quando coloco botões ao lado dos campos com label, ele fica alinhado em cima, como faço para colocar para ele ficar alinhado embaixo?

```html
<div class="box">
<div class="box-body">
    <section>
        <form method="get"
              id="formfield"
              action="rota"
              >
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
                    <label for="dataini">Data Ini:</label>
                    <input type="date"
                            id="dataini"
                            name="dataini"
                            class="form-control"
                            placeholder="00/00/0000"
                            >
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
                    <label for="datafim">Data Fim:</label>
                    <input type="date"
                            id="datafim"
                            name="datafim"
                            class="form-control"
                            placeholder="00/00/0000"
                            >
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1">
                    <button type="submit" id="btnFiltrar" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fas fa-search"></i> Pesquisar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </section>
</div>
```

Está ficando assim:

[image: Botão desalinhado]

Comment: Tá usando bootstrap 3 mesmo?

Comment: Sim, estou usando ele no AdminLTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bootstrap 4**
Adiciona essa classe junto ao item que tem a classe 'row'

```
align-items-end
```

**Bootstrap 3**

```
.container-row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
.bottom-column {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Lembrando que a classe "container-row" vai ser adicionada junto a classe "row" e a "bottom-column" junto com as classes que estão com a coluna do botao

Comment: Funcionou perfeito! Obrigado.

Comment: Fico feliz em ajudar... se possível... marque a resposta como válida 

Comment: Ainda não consigo marcar como válida por enquanto, mas assim que puder, o farei. Obrigado novamente.

Comment: Guilherme, poderia me dizer como faço para alinhar no meio da linha?